# About Skanda Shasti Fasting

Tags: puranas, kartikeya, fasting

Skanda Shasti is a famous festival in Tamilnadu. I want to know
what is Skanda Shasti and Skanda Shasti Fasting? How to observe this fasting and pooja?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skanda is Lord Shiva & Goddess Parvati's son,younger brother of Ganapaty, also known by names such as Karthikeya,Shanmuga etc.

The Puranas say that Karthikeya was born on **Sukla Shashti tithi in the MArgasirsha** month.Hence the name [Skanda Shasti](http://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/skanda-sashti-dates.html),which is the day/vrata dedicated to [Lord Karthikeya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya).Just like the [Ekadashi Tithis](http://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/ekadashidates.html) are dedicated to Vratas related to Lord Vishnu ,Chaturthi Tithis to Lord Ganapaty similarly the Sukla Paksha Shasti Tithi is dedicated to Lord Karthikeya.

> Sashti Tithi is dedicated to Lord Skanda. Devotees keep fast during
>   Shukla Paksha Sashti day. For Skanda Sashti Vratam the day when Sashti
>   Tithi is combined with Panchami Tithi is preferred. Hence Skanda
>   Sashti Vratam might be observed on Panchami Tithi.
>
> Skanda Sashti is also known as Kanda Shashti

The [Varaha Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=13) describes the origin & importance of Skanda Shasti as follows:

> T**he birth of Kartikeya at the Krittika Star on the Sixth day of the
>   bright fortnight of Margasira month (Krittika Nakshatra of Shashthi
>   Tithi of Suddha Paksha of Margasirsha Month)** brought relief to the
>   Universe, immense joy to the Siva Couple, sense of liberation to all
>   Devas who were indeed the direct beneficiaries since Brahma�s boon was
>   that only Siva�s son could terminate the Demon Tarakasura and finally
>   great fear and apprehension to Tarakasura and followers! **Brahma had formally declared Shashthi of every month would be a day of austerity and fast only with �Phalaahar� or fruits as food. Those who are deviod of sons, prosperity and status ought to observe the fast and recite the above Karikeya Stuti for instant results.**

The Karthikeya Stuti referred to in the passage above is this:

> *�Bhavasva Deva Senani Maheswarastuta Prabho Shanmukha Kanda Visvesha kukkutadwaja Paavake- Kampitare Kumaresha Skanda Balagrahnuga Jitaare
>   Krounchavidhvamsa Krittikasuta Matruja- Bhutagrahapati sreshtha
>   Paavaki Priya Darshana, Maha Bhutapateh Putra Trilochana Namostutey-
>   Yvam Stutastada Devaihi vavardha Bhavanandanah, Dwadasaadithya samkaso
>   vabhuvaadhuta Darshanah Trilokyamapi tattejasthaapayamaasa Parthiva!�*

One who knows tamil can also recite the famous [Kanda Shasti Kavacham](http://murugan.org/texts/ksk_tamil&english.htm)  on the Vrata days.